# Box-Shadow compiling from SCSS but not showing in Firebug; using Compass

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, compass-sass, html5boilerplate

I'm using Bones HTML5 Boilerplate starter template for WordPress (also linking to Bootstrap CDN).  I've imported compass in my main .scss file:

```css
@import "compass";
```

and when I use the following markup in the partial:

```css
.wp-image-6 {
    @include box-shadow(5px,5px,3px, #888);
    border-radius: 2em;
}
```

The code seems to compile fine in my style.css file:

```css
.wp-image-6 {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px, 5px, 3px, #888888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px, 5px, 3px, #888888;
    box-shadow: 5px, 5px, 3px, #888888;
    border-radius: 2em;
}
```

However, when I inspect with Firebug (or Safari), the selector shows only the border-radius (which does work on the image I'm testing).

```css
.wp-image-6 {
    border-radius: 2em;
}
```

And if I view the style.css from the browser (by clicking on the style.css link in the head section for example), it shows the styling:

```css
 .wp-image-6 {
     -webkit-box-shadow: 5px, 5px, 3px, #888888;
     -moz-box-shadow: 5px, 5px, 3px, #888888;
     box-shadow: 5px, 5px, 3px, #888888;
     border-radius: 2em;
 }
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening (box-shadow not working)?  Thank you for any help.

Comment: It isn't showing up in firebug because those are computed values, not what is necessarily in the stylesheet.  What elements are you using the `.wp-image-6` class on?  I have a feeling this is an issue with specificity.

Comment: I've tried a few different elements.  I tried putting shadowing on any div, a sidebar, and img tag (the element for the class described above).  Doesn't work on anything.  What does it matter that the values are computed?  Also, I just tried this include for border radius:  `@include border-radius(1em);` and it worked, compiled to the style.css file and altered the image.  It appears there's something going on that's overriding box-shadow with my setup, not sure, thank you for your help!

Comment: Oh, you know what... it's because you have unnecessary commas. Try `@include box-shadow(5px 5px 3px #888);` instead of `@include box-shadow(5px,5px,3px, #888);`

Comment: my god i'm an idiot some times.  Thank you.  I guess I should delete this question?

Comment: Haha, it happens sometimes.  I'll just put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mixin you have commas where you don't need them.  Use

`@include box-shadow(5px 5px 3px #888);`

instead of:

`@include box-shadow(5px,5px,3px, #888);`